# Calling class based on a dynamic variable in c#

Tags: c#

I have several classes that I want to access from another class based on a variable from the calling class.

I know one possible way of accomplishing it by using switch statements but I'm trying to see of another easier solution for it.

Here is the class I want to call from

```
namespace sample
{
public class callingClass{
  public string ClassName:

  public void loadVar(){
  //I want to call the class and it's methods based on value of ClassName variable. The  classname here is dynamic. It is being set from another class. 

    Get_ClassName classname = new Get_ClassName();
    ClassName =classname.Name

//how can I use this ClassName variable to access

// looking for something like this

ClassName NewVar= new ClassName();
NewVar.Set_variable();
}


}

}
```

```
namespace sample
{
public class Test_A{
public override void set_variable(){

//Set some variables here
public string Var1="TestA";
}

}
```

```
namespace sample{
public class Test_B{
public override void set_variable(){
//Set some variables here
public string Var1="TestB";
}
}
}
```

```
namespace sample 
{

public class Test_C{
public override void set_variable(){
//Set some variables here

public string Var1="TestC";
}
}

}
```

Comment: You can use `Type.GetType` to get a type by name, `Activator.CreateInstance` to create an instance, then use dynamic typing for the rest, if you *really* don't want to use an interface. I would advise you to follow .NET naming conventions, use readable formatting, and write code which will compile as far as possible for sample code in Stack Overflow questions, by the way. There's no reason to use pseudo-code other than for the *one* bit you don't know how to achieve.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: I suggest you tidy up the question, following normal .NET naming conventions, providing a minimal *complete* example which we should be able to run once the "missing" bit is fixed, and explain how far you've got using `Type.GetType` and `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Comment: I tried the following but I get an error "object does not contain a definition for "set_variable". ` Type type= Type.GetType(ClassName); and var newInstance=Activator.CreateInstance(type);   newInstance.set_variable();`

Comment: Well yes - if you want to use dynamic typing, you'll need to declare the type of `newInstance` as `dynamic`. (It would still be better to make all the classes implement an interface though...)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am all good now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need some polymorphism. Create interface, implement to your Test classes and call them inside main class from inner field with type of that interface. Calling classes by varible name is not good.

```
public class CallingClass {
    public ITest TestClass; 

    // now you can call  CallingClass.TestClass.AnyITestInterfaceMethod()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solve my problem:

```
namespace sample
{
public class callingClass{
  public string ClassName:

  public void loadVar(){
 

    Get_ClassName classname = new Get_ClassName();
    ClassName =classname.Name
Type type = Type.GetType(ClassName);
dynamic NewInstance= Activator.CreateInstance(type);
//now i can access the methods and variables like this:
NewInstance.Set_variable();
NewInstance.Var1
}


}

}
```